# Camel DefaultShutdownStrategy logging full url

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm having an issue where I cannot prevent the shutdown strategy in camel from logging my full URL. This is a problem because the URL has a password in it.

Neither of the `.logMask()` calls suppress this log line. How can I go about preventing this from being logged?

```java
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(uriString)
            .logMask()
            .process(exchange -> {
                Message in = exchange.getIn();
                // Doing some business logic here
            })
            .toD("direct:someOtherRoute")
            .logMask();
        }
});
```

The line being logged:

```
kafka://MY-TOPIC-NAME?saslJaasConfig=passwordThatShouldNotBeLogged&otherParams...
```

Edit: The full url is being logged both on startup and shutdown.

Comment: Do you use logback for logging? If so, you can define a `CompositConverter`, register it within your logback configuration and check whether the logline to log contains a password that you can then obfuscate or remove. Through `Marker`, which can also be defined in Camel, one can specify that this special handling should only kick in in the presence or absence of such a defined log-marker

Comment: What Camel version do you use? And can you provide a more real example of the value of the saslJaasConfig you are using?

Comment: I created a ticket at Apache Camel: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this information is logged by Camel. But we have fixed this for next releases (2.25.0 onwards, and the 3.x branches).

For your current version, you cannot prevent this. However you can configure the logging level for that shutdown class to be WARN level.

You can also patch your Camel version yourself, this is the commit
https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/f60e4a73935bea211eec38823698d73bd1d0bd62

Answer (score 1):

If your sensitive endpoint parameters are for SSL configuration, you can register the SSL configuration in the Camel Context and only reference it in the endpoint parameters.

```
kafka://MY-TOPIC-NAME?sslContextParameters=#ssl
```

See the [Camel-Kafka Docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html#_ssl_configuration) (section SSL Configuration) for details.

Comment: Thanks. The password is in the `saslJaasConfig` parameter though. I'll edit my question to be more specific